# Why does compiling my Biztalk 2009 project lock files?

Tags: locking, biztalk

Once you first build your BizTalk projects, the next time you go to make a change in one of the assemblies and then rebuild the solution the project output dlls are all locked by visual studio.

Error    11    Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Mits.Rar.Schemas.dll" to "bin\Debug\Mits.Rar.Schemas.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Mits.Rar.Schemas.dll' because it is being used by another process.    Mits.Rar.Schemas

The only way I can workaround this is to close visual studio and restart it. This causes me to do this 100s of times a day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the BizTalk 2009 VS support has a bunch of bugs :(. I'm not sure if this will help the specific issue you're seeing, but might be worth a try:
http://pim.waaijenberg.net/index.php/2009/08/copy-local-that-biztalk-2009-reference/